# How to set the remote host using slurp in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, slurp

I would like to read a remote file content in an Ansible playbook.

```
- name: Load spark defaults
  slurp:
    src: /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
  register: spark_defaults

- debug:
    msg: "{{ spark_defaults['content'] | b64decode }}"
```

I have read the documentation of both [slurp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html) and [fetch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-fetch-module) and both mention they are intended to get the remote file.
But the available parameters does not have the host.

I tried:

```
- name: Load spark defaults
  slurp:
    src: my.host://etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
  register: spark_defaults
```

```
- name: Load spark defaults
  slurp:
    src: me@my.host://etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
  register: spark_defaults
```

but cant seem to get it work.
I guess I miss something fundamental and will really appreciate help here.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question I figure out the answer. I hope it helps others:
the secret is to use `delegate_to`

```
- name: Load spark defaults
  slurp:
    src: /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
  delegate_to: my.host
  remote_user: me
  register: spark_defaults
```